# Is it OK to retrospectively close as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, etiquette

Suppose a question is asked, answered and accepted, then at some later date another duplicate question is asked, also answered and accepted, but no one picks up the duplication.

If the second question/answer is "better" (more votes for both question and answer), is it OK to close the first question as a duplicate, even though at the time it was posed it was a new question?

It seems OK to me, but there may be some etiquette aspect I'm not considering.

Comment: I see it all the time, especially on Meta with unimplemented feature requests. Sometimes future posts are more specific/better posts and get more upvotes.

Comment: @random Oh, this is so ironic...

Comment: `[3 duplicates later]`

Comment: @michaelb958 I was afraid this might happen... I searched for "retrospective" :/